# What is a good method for applying grid search on ensemble models?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, hyperparameter, ensemble-learning

I built an experiment where i am studying the performance of ensemble models for a classification task. Basically, i'm comparing Random Forest with Adaboost. However, Adaboost is built with a mix of different base classifiers (i.e. neural networks + decision trees + any other classifier).

I can explore Random Forest through grid search just varying the number of decision trees that are used. However, i have no clue about how to properly explore this "mixed" Adaboost models, since its performance doesn't vary only with the number of estimators, but also with the hyperparameters of the base classifiers as well.

I mean, i could just explore the best hyperparameters for each classifier individually and then just run grid search varying the number of base classifiers, but the idea of using ensembles is that simpler classifiers - when combined - perform better than a single robust one.

I'd like to know if anyone has a good method for this case. I'd like to combine many different classifiers with Adaboost.

Comment: How exactly do you use AdaBoost with a mix of classifiers? What is the purpose of your experiment?

Comment: In fact, this is the purpose of the experiment - to identify how well Adaboost can perform with the diversity of base estimators. I can combine, for instance, MLP + Logistic Regression + KNN, or just a bunch of MLPs, or everything else you can imagine. I just want to understand how can i define a pipeline to explore all parameters through grid search

Comment: Seems like the *whole point* of your research is coming up with a novel algorithm, inspired by AdaBoost. This shouldn't really be a Q&A question. If you don't have yet a reasonable solution, the whole the comparison would only show that an arbitrary algorithm does not outperform an algorithm that is known to work. Also, why comparing to random forest and not AdaBoost itself?